# SwiftUI using Enum across module

Tags: swiftui, dependency-injection, solid-principles, abstraction, modular-design

I am trying to use an enum across multiple modules as follows

```
// ComponentsModule
public struct FloatView: View {
    
    var str: String
    
    public init(str: String) {
        self.str = str
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        Text("I am A float displaying: \(str)")
    }
}

// PopupModule
import ComponentsModule
import SubscriptionModule // circular dependency !!!

public enum PopupItem: View {
    case float(String)
    case sheet(SubscriptionType) // need to import SubscriptionModule to gain access to SubscriptionType
    
    public var body: some View {
        switch self {
        case .float(let string):
            FloatView(str: string)
        case .sheet(let subscriptionType):
            SubscriptionView(subscriptionType: subscriptionType) // need to import SubscriptionModule to gain access to SubscriptionView
        }
    }
}

// SubscriptionModule
// SubscriptionType, SubscriptionView, SubscriptionViewViewModel and SubscriptionService live inside Subscription Module

import PopupModule // // circular dependency !!!

public struct SubscriptionType {
    var name: String
}

public struct SubscriptionView: View {
    @StateObject private var vm = SubscriptionViewViewModel()
    
    var subscriptionType: SubscriptionType
    
    public init(subscriptionType: SubscriptionType) {
        self.subscriptionType = subscriptionType
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        Text("Your Subscription type is: \(subscriptionType.name)")
    }
}

public final class SubscriptionViewViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    private var subscriptionService: SubscriptionServiceProtocol
    
    public init(
        subscriptionService: SubscriptionServiceProtocol = SubscriptionService()
    ) {
        self.subscriptionService = subscriptionService
    }
    
    private func loadSubscriptionType() {
        let subscriptionType = subscriptionService.getSubscriptionType()
        let popupItem: PopupItem = .sheet(subscriptionType) // need to import PopupModule to gain access to PopupItem
        
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("subscriptionType"), object: popupItem) // PopupItem used elsewhere in the code via an observer        }
}

public protocol SubscriptionServiceProtocol {
    func getSubscriptionType() -> SubscriptionType
}
public final class SubscriptionService: SubscriptionServiceProtocol {
    
    public init() {}
    
    public func getSubscriptionType() -> SubscriptionType {
        SubscriptionType(name: "Cold")
    }
}
```

How do I employ SOLID principles, Dependency Injection, Composition Root, sharing Views across multiple modules or any other architectural or design principals to completely decouple the modules and achieve this design without running into issues like circular dependency etc. The SubscriptionViewViewModel is initialized in main App and shared accross the app via EnvironmentObject

Thought i would create in an AbstractionModule a protocol

```
public protocol PopupItemProtocol {
    case float(String)
    case sheet(SubscriptionType)
}
```

and witness it with PopupItem, then use

```
PopupItemProtocol.float("Some text")
```

in a module that imports only the AbstractionModule, but turns out i need the conforming type i.e PopupItem, so dead end there.

Comment: Your question is way broad but using swift packages can be a good start to create separate concerns between modules and enforce decoupling

Comment: @JoakimDanielson ComponentsModule,  PopupModule and SubscriptionModule are different modules in the same package(for ease of maintenance). Those are separate concerns. How to achieve that decoupling.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine View is a protocol

Comment: github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/… should sort me out with dependency inversion. Will get back how far it goes

Comment: yes ok, View is a protocol.

Comment: See edit for what I thought would help.